# how to show records in diiferent view with date filter in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

i have one view called Index on which i am using modes to display view the modes 
are Issue and Recieved mode issue is showing different records and recieved showing different records.on the index view i have one datepicker and a button on selection of any date and clicking on the button i want to show records which is matching that particular date but in different view i don't understand how to achieve that i am using jquery post method through which i am passing date value

Here is my cshtml and jquery

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-7 offset-4">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input id="date" class="eadate form-control" />
            <button id="print" class="print btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    $(function() {
        $('#print').click(function () {
            var Date = $('#date').val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("Records", "LaundryFirm")', { dateval: Date });
        });

    });

here is my controller method

        public ActionResult Records(DateTime? dateval)
        {
            var res = db.Query<RoomLaundryvw>($"Select rm.RoomID,rm.RoomNo,g.GuestID,g.GuestName,ln.ReservationID,ity.ItemTypeName,it.ItemName,ln.PickDate,ln.DropDate from Laundry ln " +
                    "inner join Items it on ln.ItemId = it.ItemId " +
                    "inner join ItemTypes ity on ity.ItemTypeId = it.ItemTypeId " +
                    "inner join Rooms rm on ln.RoomID = rm.RoomID " +
                    "left join Reservation_Guest rg on rg.ReservationID = ln.ReservationID " +
                    "left join Guests g on g.GuestID = rg.GuestID " +
                   $"where ln.PickDate = '{dateval}'").ToList();
            return View("Records", res);
        }
```

eadate class is pointing to datepicker in this case, on debugger mode i am getting the value of selecetd date but the problem is i am not redirecting to Records view with respective records of that date.Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Question is too unclear but as I guess you want to show data after onClick #print button

instead of  
**return View("Records", res);**

use 
 **return PartialView("Records", res);**

and change call function as

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Records", "LaundryFirm")';
$('#print').click(function() {
  var Date = $('#date').val();
  $('#result').load(url, { dateval: Date });
})
```

and after button or wherever you want add div with id = result

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-7 offset-4">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input id="date" class="eadate form-control" />
      <button id="print" class="print btn btn-default"> <i class="fas fa-print"></i> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: i want to show data with the parameters in seperate view